# How routing works in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my route file I have some route like below. What this means? I looked in rails route guide but I can not find explanation for => and foo: 'bar'

```
get '/clients/:status' => 'clients#index', foo: 'bar'
```

Please explain what this means?

Comment: `string => string` is a Hash key/value, so is `symbol: string`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, I will assume your web server is running at the host and port `localhost:3000`. But that part isn't important - whatever the host and port are that get the request to Rails it is all the same.

```
get '/clients/:status' => 'clients#index', foo: 'bar'
```

If you are not familiar with Ruby syntactic sugar, this is equivalent to:

```
get({'/clients/:status' => 'clients#index', :foo => 'bar'})
```

From here, let me break it down piece by piece:

- The `get` means that the route applies only to "GET" HTTP requests.
- `'/clients/:status'` means to apply this route to a request for `http://localhost:3000/clients/:status` where `:status` is any string
- `=> 'clients#index'` tells Rails that it should call the code in ClientsController's `index` method.
- `:foo => 'bar'` is probably something more meaningful in whatever you want to do (as vee mentions), but in this case, (I think) it will be added as a value in the `params` hash that is accessible in ClientsController`s`index` method.

For more information, check out the Rails guide on Routing. It's one of the best pieces of Rails documentation, IMHO:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

Answer (score 4):

It means that for a HTTP GET request to a URI of pattern `/clients/:status` where `:status` is the variable parameter.

The `=> clients#index` stands for `Controller#action` where `controller` is `clients` i.e. `ClientsController` and `action` is `index`.

The third option you have `foo: 'bar'` is basically other options to the route definition.  Other options such as `as`, `constraints` and so on.

For example with `as` (which lets you name your route):

```
get '/clients/:status' => 'clients#index', as: :client_status
```

Here `as: :client_status` would replace your `foo: 'bar'`.